# Android Webview not loading linkedin page

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load linkedin page in webview but i can only see linkedin logo but i tried loading facebook and it facebook successfully. Here is my code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.loadUrl("https://www.linkedin.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable javascript in your WebView like this:-

```
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I tried with this but no use.. its working in emulator but not in real device.